# Angle brackets in String disappear on JSP using Tomcat 6

Tags: jsp, tomcat6, sparql, jena

I got a problem using Jena/ARQ on my JSP application deployed on Tomcat 6. I want to query a SPARQL endpoint with following query:

```
String query = "prefix dbpprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/> select ?population where { " +   
                res_dbpedia.getURI() + " dbpprop:population ?population . }";
```

that then i submit correctly

```
qexecDBPedia = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService(sparqlEnpointDBPedia, 
                                                   sparqlQS_DBPedia);
resultsDBPedia = qexecDBPedia.execSelect();`
```

I got an error because in the String query all the angle brackets are removed:

```
prefix dbpprop: select ?population where { dbpprop:population ?population . }
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean:

```
String query = "prefix dbpprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/> " +
               "select ?population where { <" +   
                res_dbpedia.getURI() + "> dbpprop:population ?population . }";
```

(sorry for rewrapping)

Note that you didn't have `<>` around `res_dbpedia.getURI()`.

Comment: Yes, it was with "<". I solved the problem anyway and was not about "<".